# Google Drive API 400 error when uploading large file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm writing an upload script that uploads CSV files to a Google Drive folder using resumable uploads - am using this as a reference

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload

See the code below.

It seems to work file for files of size <= 20MB, but bigger files are causing problems.

I've got a 43 MB CSV file which I am trying to upload using a chunk size of 5 MiB but am getting a 400 error on the last chunk upload:

```
file_meta = {'title': 'test.csv', 'description': 'Test CSV', 'mimeType': 'text/csv', 'parents': [{'id': myfolder_key}]}
convert_to_Google_Sheets = True
chunk_size = 1024*1024*5
content = <MediaIoBaseUpload object, resumable, 5 MiB chunk size>
req = drive.files().insert(body=file_meta, media_body=content, convert=convert_to_Google_Sheets)
response is None
while not response:
  status, response = req.next_chunk()
  if status:
    print "Uploaded %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

The upload seems to progress fine until we get to the last chunk, when it terminates with a 400 error:

```
Uploaded 11%.
Uploaded 23%.
Uploaded 34%.
Uploaded 46%.
Uploaded 57%.
Uploaded 69%.
Uploaded 81%.
Uploaded 92%.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 880, in next_chunk
    return self._process_response(resp, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 907, in _process_response
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&convert=true&alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

Comment: You may possibly want to try with multipart upload. As it is explained in the Drive documentation - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, and was stuck thinking the issue was the file size, but it turned out the file size was just an artifact of the problem.

The issue is that there is a limit of 2 million cells per spreadsheet [1], and when my (and probably yours) CSV file got around 20MB the count of columns * rows breached the 2 million cell limit.

[1] https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en